# Database: Can java.sql.Timestamp be stored in a oracle database?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I wanted to know if java.sql.Timestamp can be stored in a oracle database. In teh oracle database the column type is TIMESTAMP? Sorry, i can not try it out myself as I dont have a oracle database, and i need it urgently for a project!

Comment: A side note: if you don't have access to an oracle db, how are you planning to test your project?

Comment: so, teh code looks something like: java.sql.Timestamp timeOfLog= new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

Comment: I am giving it to the other team, but I dont want to make such a small mistake and waste  time trying to figure it out

Comment: But, to the question, yes, it should work.  I did something like that back in years 2000-2001 or so, working with java 1.3 and oracle 8i, I believe. I would use code `java.sql.Timestamp timeOfLog = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use an Oracle TIMESTAMP(6) to map to a java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: thank for the input. I will try this out and get back to you :D, but it looks correct to me on the first go

Answer (score 2):

In addition to cagcowboy's answer: you can even store a `java.sql.Timestamp` into an Oracle `DATE` column (as Oracle's DATE includes a time part)

Btw: details about the Oracle data types can be found in the manual, you don't need a running Oracle for that:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref116

Comment: You can, but you lose the fractions of seconds.  These may or may not be important for a given application.